# How can I make such a table?

Tags: multicolumn, multicol

I am trying to make a graph with multiple columns below a column. At the moment I only got that far:
[image]

What is wrong with that? I need "DFM" and "BM" to be once below "2005-2014" and once below "2015-2020". I would also like to insert a shorter horizontal line for below the 2 columns "DFM" and "BM", again once below "2005-2014" and once below "2015-2020".

Can anyone help me do that?

I post below the most recent attempt to do it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
      
\usepackage{graphicx}% Package necessary to put graphics in your TeX document
\captionsetup[table]{font={stretch=1}}     %% change 1.2 as you like
\captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=1}}    %% change 1.2 as you like
\usepackage{threeparttable}           
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multirow}    
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
\captionsetup{font=large, labelfont=bf}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Forecast Evaluation}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc} 

      \toprule

    \textbf{Horizon} & \textbf{2005-2014} & \textbf{Horizon} & \textbf{2015-2020}  \tabularnewline

      \midrule

\multicolumn{1}{c}{DFM} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BM} \\

\cline{2-3}

    1  & Daily & 1 & No delay  \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
    2 & Daily &  4 & No delay  \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
    3 & Daily & 6 & No delay  \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
    4 & Daily &  8 & No delay  \tabularnewline

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\small
\item\hskip -\fontdimen2\font\textit{Note}: Ciao
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can use LaTeX table generator. [Here](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
      
\usepackage{graphicx}% Package necessary to put graphics in your TeX document
% \captionsetup[table]{font={stretch=1}}     %% change 1.2 as you like
% \captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=1}}    %% change 1.2 as you like
\usepackage{threeparttable}           
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multirow}    
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
% \captionsetup{font=large, labelfont=bf}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Forecast Evaluation}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc} 

      \toprule

    \textbf{Horizon}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{2005-2014}} & \textbf{Horizon} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{2015-2020}}  \\

      \midrule

                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{DFM} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BM} & &\multicolumn{1}{c}{DFM} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BM}\\

\cline{2-3}\cline{5-6}


    1  & Daily & 1 & No delay  \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
    2 & Daily &  4 & No delay  \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
    3 & Daily & 6 & No delay  \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
    4 & Daily &  8 & No delay  \tabularnewline

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\small
\item\hskip -\fontdimen2\font\textit{Note}: Ciao
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I offer you three options. The first is what I think you ask for, the second is what I think you are trying to do (because of the `\multicolumn`s). And finally, the third is what it looks better (for me, and I don't know the meaning of the table data).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

% only to put all the tables in the same page:
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=15mm,bottom=15mm}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Forecast Evaluation}
\begin{tabular}{cccc} 
\toprule
\textbf{Horizon} & \textbf{2005--2014} & \textbf{Horizon} & \textbf{2015--2020}  \tabularnewline
\midrule
& DFM & & BM\\
\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{4-4}
1 & Daily & 1 & No delay\tabularnewline\addlinespace
2 & Daily & 4 & No delay\tabularnewline\addlinespace
3 & Daily & 6 & No delay\tabularnewline\addlinespace
4 & Daily & 8 & No delay\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item\small\hskip -\fontdimen2\font\textit{Note}: Ciao
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Forecast Evaluation}
\begin{tabular}{cccc} 
\toprule
\textbf{Horizon} & \textbf{2005--2014} & \textbf{Horizon} & \textbf{2015--2020}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{DFM} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BM}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-4}
1 & Daily & 1 & No delay\tabularnewline\addlinespace
2 & Daily & 4 & No delay\tabularnewline\addlinespace
3 & Daily & 6 & No delay\tabularnewline\addlinespace
4 & Daily & 8 & No delay\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item\small\hskip -\fontdimen2\font\textit{Note}: Ciao
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Forecast Evaluation}
\begin{tabular}{cccc} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries DFM} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries BM}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-4}
Horizon & 2005--2014 & Horizon & 2015--2020\tabularnewline
\midrule
1 & Daily & 1 & No delay\tabularnewline\addlinespace
2 & Daily & 4 & No delay\tabularnewline\addlinespace
3 & Daily & 6 & No delay\tabularnewline\addlinespace
4 & Daily & 8 & No delay\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item\small\hskip -\fontdimen2\font\textit{Note}: Ciao
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]